# Informatica: How to transform rows into column using Normalizer in Informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

How to perform this transformation using Normalizer?

Input file:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
a|b|c|d
e|f|g|h
i|j|k|l
```

Output file should be:

```
col1,col2,col3
a,e,i
b,f,j
c,g,k
d,h,l
```

Answer (score -1):

Source Qualifier->Normalizer->Expression->Aggregator->Target Definition

You can also refer to [this](http://bispinformatica.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/informatica-how-to-series-transposing-rows-to-columns/) link for more details.

Comment: Question was without using Normalizer